# how to change datatype of a column while reading from a csv file

Tags: python, mysql, opencsv

i need to read a csv and do the insert operation onto the mysql db.
I was told to write it in python But not using pandas.
But while passing these to db insert  iam getting a error relating to datatype .
As by reading from csv i am getting all columns as string and in my dbtable some column has datatype as float and varchar mixe3d.
so in 
for row in csv_data:

```
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO testcsv(names, \
          classes, marks )' \
          'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")', 
          row)
```

type mismatch is happening.
So please help me in
 csv_data = csv.reader(open('D:/satya.csv'))

can i add some conditions or something so that my first column will rename as string and other two will become float type.
Or after reading is there any way to read one one column and change its datatype. and later pass it to db having same dtype.
So that i can write

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO testcsv(names, \
              classes, marks )' \
              'VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")'
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost okay, what it lacks is correct formatting. To format a string with `%` you actually need to use `%` operator:

```
cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO testcsv(names, classes, marks) \
    VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")' % row
)
```

assuming that your `row` is a 3-element `tuple`. Also if you want to insert a numerical value instead of string, just remove double quotes `"..."` in your query string.

Comment: by removing only " " not worked for me but using your suggestion i did     cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO testcsv(names, classes, marks) \
    VALUES("%s", "%f", "%f")' % (row[0],float(row[1]),float(row[2])
)       This worked for me.